# How to loop though List<Pair>> iterator

Tags: java, loops, iterator

I have a method that loops through a map containing a `<Key, <List<Pair>>`. How would I loop through this and get all results? As this list contains multiple currencies. I don't want the different type of currency amounts to add together. My attempt is below, it seems to not be picking up all the results

Comment: You didn't show the entire implementation... Where is your `next`? What's `currentElement`? Hint: the error should be in line `if (currentElement != null)`

Comment: some input and output example will be the better

Comment: @AndrewTobilko update code

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Date, List<Pair<BigDecimal, Currency>>> map = ...
map.forEach((date, list) -> {
    list.forEach(pair -> {
        // business logic here
    });
});
```

This will loop through the map, and in turn loop through every list. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

EDIT (without Java 8)

```
for (Map.Entry<Date, List<Pair<BigDecimal, Currency>>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Date date = entry.getKey();
    List<Pair<BigDecimal, Currency>> list = entry.getValue();
    for (Pair<BigDecimal, Currency> pair : list) {
        BigDecimal bd = pair.getKey();
        Currency currency = pair.getValue();
        //business logic here
    }
}
```

It's slightly less elegant (I guess that's a reason to upgrade to Java 8), but functionally equivalent to the first solution (with slight scope/variable name differences). the `for (T t : Iterable<T>)` syntax was introduced in Java 5 with the `Iterable` interface, so this should work for practically everyone.

EDIT (If specifically using `Iterator`)

```
while (source.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Date, List<Pair<BigDecimal, Currency>>> entry = source.next();
    Date date = entry.getKey();
    List<Pair<BigDecimal, Currency>> list = entry.getValue();
    for (Pair<BigDecimal, Currency> pair : list) {
        BigDecimal bd = pair.getKey();
        Currency currency = pair.getValue();
        //business logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Dang, your answer is way more elegant than mine :)

Comment: I believe forEach was added in java 8, which I am currently not able to use

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a version that works with earlier versions.

Comment: Just a couple of questions, I'm having trouble with the last part of the first line map.entrySet()) {  it doesnt seem to like this. Secondly how would I then add the 3 values(Date, BigDecimal and currency) to my Element object?

Comment: What error are you getting with map.entrySet(). This is a method on the Map interface and exists before Java 8. Also, creating an Element object will depend on how your Element class is structured. I have edited the loop body slightly. (Note, inside the loop you have access to the variables "date", "pair", "bd" (bigDecimal) and "currency". These should be enough to construct your Element object

Comment: You say in the question you have a map containing <Key, List<Pair>>. Rename "map" to whatever the name of your map is.

Comment: source is the map, updated my code above to show what I mean.

Comment: Edited to use `Iterator source`

Comment: Thanks so this is now working 90% correctly however when I add in currentElement = new Element(date, bd, currency);inside the loop It appears to only be writing at the end of the loop..not for every item in the list. Any idea as to why that would be occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Map which contains all of your data you could do something like this:

```
Iterator<Entry<Date, List<Pair<BigDecimal, Currency>>>> itr = source.entrySet().iterator();
```

Now that you have this Iterator, you can convert it to an Element iterator:

```
Iterator<Element> eItr = new Iterator<Element> {
    int index = 0;
    Iterator<Entry<Date, List<Pair<BigDecimal, Currency>>>> itr = source.entrySet().iterator();
    Entry<Date, List<Pair<BigDecimal, Currency>>> current = itr.hasNext()? itr.next() : null;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Element next() {
        try {
            return new Element(current.getKey(), current.getValue().get(index).getFirst(), current.getValue().get(index).getSeccond());
        } finally {
            index++;
            if (index >= current.getValue().size()) {
                index = 0;
                current = itr.hasNext()? itr.next() : null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```